# how to make linked list have child node

Tags: c++

My problem is how can i create linked list and each node in it has two pointer each pointer point to two different nodes exactly like the picture

http://tinypic.com/r/1444apy/5

I am trying to create two classes but I did not know how to combine these classes to make each node have child

```
class  Department

{

string name; //name of the department

int numStudents; //number of students in the department

Department* next; //this pointer will point to the next department


};




class  College 


{


string name; //for name of the college


int numDepartments; //number of departments in this college

Department* dep; //this will point to the department in this college

College * next; //the next pointer to point to the next college
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to treat each of your nodes like the `College` ones - i.e. each node will have a pointer to the next one, and a pointer to the child one. For nodes that don't have children (on your picture, the `Department` nodes), just set the child (`dep`) pointer to NULL.

Comment: (I assume that you want to create a generic `Node` class that can represent either college or department, right?)

Comment: I am trying to solve this question ->                       Q1\University Database
Assume that you are designing a university’s database which has several colleges and within each college it has several departments. So you need to create a database using linked list that represent a university’s college and department structure.

Comment: @user2999343 - then your original solution seems fine, it doesn't specify what has to be a part of the linked list. In your solution, you have a linked list of colleges, each of which contains a linked list of departments.